# Who said it first?

Tags: etymology

"If you think you are too small to make a difference, you haven't spent the night with a mosquito"
Is this an African proverb or is it originally from the Dalai Lama?

Comment: Wrong forum for this question.

Comment: @GEdgar Questions about etymology are very much on topic for this forum.

Comment: I don’t think this falls under the standard definition of etymology.

Comment: Why have 4 people voted to close because, they say, this question "isn't about English"? It looks like English to me, and although who-said-it-first questions are disparaged by some, they are on-topic for this forum...**with research**.

Answer (score 1):

According to the link [here](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7777-if-you-think-you-are-too-small-to-make-a), it was said by Dalai Lama.

Comment: Please edit your post to follow our [Help Center's guidelines on how to reference other sites](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). It is not sufficient to include merely a link, because the source of the quotation must be able to survive a plain-text (or plain-paper) transformation intact without loss of information explaining who said it and where it's from.